# Error: could not find function "%||%" (percent pipe pipe percent)

Tags: r

Due to the characters, I'm having a hard time googling for which package the `%||%` function comes from.

I have tried googling the string literal, as well as 'percent bar bar percent' and similar.

Comment: How did you come up with that function?  Can you use it on your machine?

Comment: @KotaMori I cannot. It's used in `rvest::set_values()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is present in `rlang` package. See

```
?rlang::`%||%`
```

It behaves like `dplyr::coalesce` but for `NULL` values instead of `NA`s.

Comment: Thanks @Ronak. I learned two things (the other being that rlang isn't a base R package that loads when R does). Thanks again

Comment: Doing `?\`%||%\`` in my console gave two results. `purrr` and `rlang`. It was imported into `purrr` from `rlang`.

Comment: I see. I just updated to R 4.0.2 (and haven't installed purrr yet) which must explain why I don't see the same. Thanks again!